# How can i filter the un matched array elements alone when compare with another array objects in angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter, angular8

I have a two array response and I would like to compare the two responses and have to filter the unmatched array elements into a new array object.

**Condition to compare the two response and filter is:** *we have to filter when `code` and `number` are not matched exactly with the response two then we have to filter such an array element into a new array object which I need as an output.*

The Array element present in the Response two example is also present in the Response of Array One example which I don't want and I need to filter the array elements which is not matched with the Response of Array One.

Final Output which we filtered from the response two array will be like below which is unmatched with the response 1 array object:

```
{
  "unmatchedArrayRes": [
    {
      "code": "08",
      "number": "2323232323",
      "id": "432",
      "value": "value432"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response of Array One

```
{
   "MainData": [
       {
           "DataResponseOne": [
               {
                   "viewData": {
                       "number": "11111111111111",
                       "code": "01"
                   },
                   "name": "viewDataOne"
               },
               {
                    "viewData": {
                        "number": "22222222222222",
                        "code": "01"
                    },
                    "name": "viewDataTwo"
                },
                {
                    "viewData": {
                        "number": "3333333333333",
                        "code": "02"
                    },
                    "name": "viewDataThree"
                }
           ]
       },
       {
            "DataResponseTwo": [
                {
                    "viewData": {
                        "number": "5555555555555",
                        "code": "9090"
                    },
                    "name": "viewDataFour"
                },
                {
                    "viewData": {
                        "number": "6666666666666",
                        "code": "01"
                    },
                    "name": "viewDataFive"
                },
                {
                    "viewData": {
                        "number": "8888888888888",
                        "code": "01"
                    },
                    "name": "viewDataSix"
                }
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

Response Two Example :

```
{
  "compareRes": [
    {
      "code": "01",
      "number": "11111111111111",
      "id": "123",
      "value": "value123"
    },
    {
      "code": "9090",
      "number": "5555555555555",
      "id": "345",
      "value": "value567"
    },
    {
      "code": "08",
      "number": "2323232323",
      "id": "432",
      "value": "value432"
    }
  ],
  "metaData": "343434343434"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a combined list of all the view items from response one.

```
const combinedList = [];

res1["MainData"].forEach(data => {
    // console.log(data);
    for( let key in data) {
      // console.log(key);
      data[key].forEach(innerData => {
        console.log(innerData)
        combinedList.push(innerData["viewData"]);
      })
    }
  });
```

In the above method, It is done in such a way that it can handle multiple viewData responses like DataResponseOne, DataResponseTwo, and so on.

And then filter second response Items like this:

```
const unfilteredListItems = res2["compareRes"].filter(data => {
    return !combinedList.some(listItem => {
      return listItem.code === data.code && listItem.number === data.number;
    });
  });

  console.log(unfilteredListItems);
```

Working Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-example-aq1eik?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi Drashti, It's working fine, and thanks a lot for your help and response.